# PayU india payment Gateway integartion in iOS

Tags: shopify, payu

In India Shopify supports the following four payment gateways:

PayU India
PayU Paisa
But we have an existing merchant account with Axis Bank. I have no idea where to configure my Axis Bank Payment Gateway with Shopify.

So the question is:

How do I configure my Axis Bank Payment Gateway with Shopify?

Is it even possible to configure another payment gateway, which is not supported (not listed in their store admin panel) by Shopify?

Comment: How this question relates to iOS technology ? You are working Native or phoneGap/Sencha methodology.

Comment: ya i am working on e commerce website in iOS app

Comment: Is it Native Or CSS/HTML stuffs ?

Comment: i am using this PayU account For one of the shopping cart app in iOS

Comment: If you are working iOS Native then your approach not possible as per the guidelines of Apple. If Not then it not relates to iOS technology.

Comment: You can use alternate payment gateways for physical goods. In fact, you can't use in-app purchase for physical goods

Comment: ok any example u have or any tutorial for that.

Comment: @tomrozb Do I need Salt Key while Live/Production mode in PayUMoney?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mainly to implement your approach you have two ways :-

- Ask server guys to create a web page with payment transfer with a specific link on cloud and launch that link in your app.
- Otherwise you can use third party trusted payment gateways with their mobile applications SDK's.
- BrainTree
- zooz
- paypal and may more.

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: If there are no encryption type of stuffs by PayU then you can directly pass the parameters and open it into app.

Comment: @veeresh PayU is working for you . i have some issue

Comment: did you fix PayU india?

Comment: Do I need Salt Key while Live/Production mode in PayUMoney?

Answer (score 0):

I have uploaded a repo in github for [IOS payU Integration](https://github.com/dsrawat4u/PayUIndia_IOS_SDK)